What is the intuition behind price level determinacy in cashless and frictionless economy with Taylor-type interest rate rule?
Following Gali's Monetary Policy, Inflation, and the Business Cycle (2nd edition) chapter 2:
Frictionless + cashless economy set up and log-linearised.
We have:
Fisher Equation (with real rate determined by real factors):
$$i_{t}=E_{t}\{\pi_{t+1}\}+r_{t}$$
Interest rate rule:
$$i_{t}=\rho+\pi+\phi_{\pi}(\pi_{t}-\pi)+v_{t}$$
where $\rho\approx -log(\beta)$
And $v_{t}=\rho_{v}v_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}^{v}$
Let $\hat{\pi}_t \equiv \pi_t -\pi$ and $\hat{r_t}=r_t-\rho$
Now combine Interest rate rule and and Fisher Equation to get (equation 24):
$$\phi_{\pi} \hat{\pi}_t=E_{t}\hat{\pi}_{t+1}+\hat{r}_{t}-v_{t}$$
Solving forward where $\phi_{\pi}>1$
We get equation 25:
$$\hat{\pi}_{t}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\phi_{\pi}^{-(k+1)}E_{t}(\hat{r}_{t+k}-v_{t+k})$$
With the particular process for preference shifters, TFP and MP shock v_t this becomes:
$$\pi_{t}=\pi-\frac{\sigma(1-\rho_{a})\psi_{ya}}{\phi_{\pi}-\rho_{a}}a_{t}+\frac{1-\rho_{z}}{\phi_{\pi}-\rho_{z}}z_{t}-\frac{1}{\phi_{\pi}-\rho_{v}}v_{t}$$
This implies that a positive monetary policy shock leads to a reduction in inflation and the nominal interest rate as $\frac{\partial i_{t}}{\partial\epsilon_{t}^{v}}=\frac{-\rho_{v}}{\phi_{\pi}-\rho_{v}}$
None of the maths is unclear but I struggle for the intuition. A MP shock increases expected inflation in the next period. What mechanism generates a fall in inflation and nominal rate today?
p.s. I'm unsure if some of these equations are rendering properly. They render fine on https://www.mathjax.org
